# Cloudkitty in devstack - Setup automation

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

We know that Cloudkitty is being used as a Rating-as-a-service in Openstack.

I can be able to setup Cloudkitty in Devstack successfully.

Also I can be able to configure price as needed for the same.

But I need to create an automation script for cloudkitty to configure pricing for various size of instance as needed.

As well as need to configure for images.

**In other words:**

I Need to develop a pattern/script for leveraging the API (using the cloudkitty python library) for initial setup/injection of pricing for several instance types as well as specific additional pricing for a specific image uuid (e.g. windows licensing fee).

Please some one let me know the way for achieving the same. Atleast any sample code for this one.

Comment: Don't give negative vote without knowing what it is really meant to be.
If you are giving, then please mention the reason too.
We are opening queries here only after proper analysis on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can be able to create the solution for the same.

Here it implemented code on the same.

https://github.com/muraliselva10/cloudkitty-pricing-automation-script